# jhipster: typescript: react-cookie-consent type not found

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jhipster

I am using generator-jhipster-cookie-consent with jhipster to set up my cookie consent, However I keep getting `TS2307: Cannot find module 'react-cookie-consent' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Comment: Have you opened an issue on project's github?

Comment: I just did  and hopefully I can get a response soon. 

The opened Issue On Github: 
                    
                https://github.com/vivekmore/generator-jhipster-cookie-consent/issues/1